# Static Dropdown Menu

Tags: css

I have a question about a dropdown menu customization. I would like to have my dropdown set so that it appears on a fixed part of the screen. Please look at this screenshot:
http://snag.gy/pw12X.jpg

Currently, I have it like this:
http://snag.gy/FgqS3.jpg

Per your reference, this is the code snippet for the ul:

```
.PageMenu li ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    z-index: 10;
    top: 100% !important;
    width: 400px;

    left: 0;
    background: #262425;
    list-style-image: none;
    list-style: none;
```

}

I am very new at CSS. Is it possible to do this with some CSS code or will I have to insert a script to take care of this? If so, a nudge to the right direction would be very helpful.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding styles:

```
position: fixed;
left: 0
top: 0
```

should help you. It nails element top top left corner of a screen.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! When I change the position to "fixed", it doesn't display the dropdown at all.

Comment: set height to some value in px and display to block

Comment: That worked! I worked out some kinks and it's now working how I want it to. Thank you so much.